# MS Access (сопоставление полей из 2-ух таблицы)

Tags: sql, ms-access

Есть 3 таблицы:

1. **Measles_vaccine** (с 3 полями) (Таблица хранит в себе статические данные и является справочником) (ИД, серийный номер вакцины, дата срок годности вакцины)

   ```
     id 
     measles_sn_vaccine
     measles_expire_date
   ```
2. **Сертефикаты** (с кучей полей, вот ключевых из них)

   ```
     id 
     ID_пациента 
     Vкори
     V_measles_sn_vaccine 
     V_measles_dose_vaccine
     reVкори
     reV_measles_sn_vaccine
     reV_measles_dose_vaccine
     Врач
   ```
3. **Пациенты** (с кучей полей, вот ключевые из них)

   ```
     ID_пациента 
     Фамилия
     Имя
     Отчество
     Дата Рождения
   ```

поля **`V_measles_sn_vaccine | reV_measles_sn_vaccine`**  из таблицы **Serteficate**  заполняются через форму, данные в берутся из таблицы **Measles_vaccine** поля **measles_sn_vaccine.**

Так выглядит запрос отчета, при его запуске, мы вводим № карты пациента, и формируется отчет с его данными, включая данные из поля сертефикат.

```
SELECT Сертификаты.Код, 
       Сертификаты.ID_пациента, 
       [Фамилия] & " " & [Имя] & " " & [Отчество] AS fio, 
       Сертификаты.Врач, 
       Пациенты.ДатаРождения,
       Сертификаты.Vкори, 
       Сертификаты.V_measles_dose_vaccine, 
       Сертификаты.V_measles_SN_vaccine, 
       Сертификаты.reVкори, 
       Сертификаты.reV_measles_dose_vaccine, 
       Сертификаты.reV_measles_SN_vaccine, 
       Measles_vaccine.measles_expire_date
FROM (     Пациенты 
INNER JOIN Сертификаты ON Пациенты.ID_пациента = Сертификаты.[ID_пациента]
      ) 
INNER JOIN Measles_vaccine ON Сертификаты.V_measles_SN_vaccine = Measles_vaccine.measles_SN_vaccine
WHERE (((Сертификаты.ID_пациента)=[Укажите № Карты]));
```

Все формируется отлично, но осталась последняя задача, которую я ума не приложу как можно решить:
Мне нужно чтобы в отчете напротив значений поля **`V_measles_sn_vaccine`** и **`reV_measles_sn_vaccine`**, проставлялся срок годности из поля: **`measles_expire_date`**, т.е. простыми словами. Нужно чтобы в отчет-справке происходило сравнения значений полей из таблицы `Сертификаты` со справочником таблицы `Measles_vaccine` и по результатам успешного совпадения бралось значение из поля `measles_expire_date` и выводилось в форме.

Честно говоря, я вообще не представляю как это делать. Простым решением было бы создать дополнительных 2 поля в таблице Сертификаты, и дублировать значение поля `measles_expire_date` на стадии заполнения в форме, но дублировать одинаковые поля как-то некорректно, тем более дальше таких значений может быть больше, и таблицы превратится в кучу дублирующей информации.

Прикрепляю образец отчет-справки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Есть 2 таблицы* А в показанном далее запросе таблиц - три. *Прикрепляю образец отчет-справки.* Добавьте данные из таблиц - все использованные в запросе поля как минимум,- из которых формируется показанный отчёт.

Comment: внес дополнительную информацию по таблицам.

Comment: Пока непонятно, откуда берутся выходные значения показанной формы.

Comment: Таблица ``Measles_vaccine`` уже присоединена в запросе, Почему бы не взять ``Measles_vaccine.measles_expire_date`` также как берете ``Measles_vaccine.measles_sn_vaccine``